# Reference to a member of temporary

Tags: c++, reference, temporary-objects

Consider the following code:

```
#include <vector>

struct temp {
    int& get() { return i; }
    int i = 1;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(temp{}.get());
}
```

Is the above well-formed code or UB?

My doubts are about the reference returned from `get()`, which becomes dangling at the last semicolon. But at this point `push_back` is already evaluated, so it's ok, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

Temporaries live to the end of the full expression.  In this case, that means after `push_pack` has returned.  Since `push_back` makes a copy of the value `get` refers to, there is no dangling reference and everything will work as expected.